# Javascript trying to create my own form validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have this form which you can create an array with. I don't want the form to be created when there are some specific circumstances. I have this array and in it you can create questions and answers with a form, but I have a few rules. The array can only be created when there are more than 3 question and when every question has at least 3 answers.

My code:

```
            Checker() {
                /**
                 * @type {Question[]}
                 */
                let questions = NewArray.structure.questions;

                for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                    if (questions[i].answers.length <= 2) {
                        console.log(questions[i])
                        alert('Question number ' + i + ' has to few answers')
                    } else if (questions.length <= 2) {
                        alert('You need at least 3 questions!');
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (NewArray.Checker() === true) {
              Do something
            } else {
              Do nothing
            }
```

Here is questions the array with the questions and questions[i].answers the answers of the questions.

When It gives me the right message when there are less than 3 questions and when the first question had less than 3 answers, but when there are 3 questions and only the first one has answers, it still works which it should not. Does anybody know why?

[image: Image of the form]

Structure

```
        class Question {
            /**
             * @param {string} question
             * @param {string} prefix
             * @param {string} description
             * @param {string} display
             * @param {string} answerType
             * @param {string} multiSelect
             * @param {Answer[]} answers
             */
            constructor(question = "", prefix = "", description = "", display = "", answerType = "", multiSelect = "",
                answers = []) {
                this.question = question;
                this.prefix = prefix;
                this.description = description;
                this.display = display;
                this.answerType = answerType;
                this.multiSelect = multiSelect;
                this.answers = answers;
            }
        }


        class Answer {
            constructor(id = "", name = "") {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `questions[i].answers.length` does each question have multiple answers? or are you checking the user has at least answered 2 questions?  If the latter, then you probably want to keep the answers in a separate array, otherwise you would have to loop through the questions and check each answer

Comment: @Pete Well they are from separate arrays (I added the structure of the array) I but I call them in the question array when I create the form.